# grab focus on gtk widget

Tags: c, gtk3

In my app I have preferences dialog (modal to main) where can insert value in GTK_LIST_STORE[GTK_TREE_VIEW].

This entry are send to GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT as menu select.

When press button to open preferences dialog to edit values, I want automaticaly GTK_TREE_VIEW scroll to cell reference selected in main.

main ( GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT )

[image]

preferences dialog ( GTK_TREE_VIEW )

[image]

For example:

If in main window I select YELLOW when open preferences dialog, grab focus widget in YELLOW row

Thanks

UPDATE:

when add new entry I use:

```
ps = malloc(sizeof(preset));
ps->name = g_strdup(_("unnamed"));
ps->value = rint(gtk_adjustment_get_value(adj)) / STEPS;
settings.presets = g_list_append(settings.presets, (gpointer) ps);
buffer = g_strdup_printf("%.2f", ps->value);

gtk_list_store_append(list_store, &iter);
gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(list_store), &iter, 0, ps->name, 1, buffer, -1);

g_free(buffer);
gtk_tree_selection_unselect_all(selection);

v_scb = gtk_scrollable_get_vadjustment(GTK_SCROLLABLE(list_view));
gtk_adjustment_set_value(v_scb, gtk_adjustment_get_upper(v_scb));

gtk_combo_box_text_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(preset_combo), ps->name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gtk_tree_view_set_cursor](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-cursor) will set the cursor on the row that you tell it. [gtk_widget_grab_focus (GTK_WIDGET (treeview))](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-grab-focus) will set the focus to the treeview for you.